# Change number in input field within same parent container using buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, woocommerce

Thanks for reading!

I'm currently editing a snippet to use with WooCommerce, I'd like to place -/+ buttons on either side of the input field to control ordering (make it much easier).

I can get it to work but the current code edits all quantity fields.
Is there a way we can do this to edit only the field that is in the same parent container as the button?

***Please note:*** I cannot easily change the HTML of the input field, it's generated by WooCommerce.

[**CODEPEN:**](https://codepen.io/HIGHHIGH/pen/QzZdJv)

**JQuery:**

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.qty').prop('disabled', true);
    $(document).on('click', '.plus', function () {
        $('.qty').val(parseInt($('.qty').val()) + 1);
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.minus', function () {
        $('.qty').val(parseInt($('.qty').val()) - 1);
        if ($('.qty').val() == 0) {
            $('.qty').val(1);
        }
    });
});
```

**Front end HTML** (many instances on the page, the reason for editing only within the same parent):

```
<td class="woocommerce" data-product-id="623">
  <span class="fa fa-minus minus"></span>
  <div class="quantity">
    <label class="screen-reader-text" for="quantity_5c37ca4c2084e">Quantity</label>
    <input type="number" id="quantity_5c37ca4c2084e" class="input-text qty text" step="1" min="0" max="9" name="quantity_623" value="0" title="Qty" size="4" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" aria-labelledby="10 day quantity" disabled="">
  </div>
  <span class="fa fa-plus plus"></span>
</td>
```

Greatly appreciative of any wisdom, thank you in advance!! <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `.parent()` and `.find()` and try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.qty').prop('disabled', true);
    $(document).on('click', '.plus', function () {
        var qtyElement = $(this).parent().find('.qty');
        var currentQuantity = parseInt(qtyElement.val());
        qtyElement.val(currentQuantity + 1);
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.minus', function () {
        var qtyElement = $(this).parent().find('.qty');
        var currentQuantity = parseInt(qtyElement.val());
        qtyElement.val(currentQuantity - 1);

        if (currentQuantity == 0) {
            qtyElement.val(1);
        }
    });
});
```

By the way, in the `-` (minus) code you are setting a minimum value to 1 if the value is 0. Is this your intention? If you don't want it to be negative you could change it to:

```
if (currentQuantity <= 0) {
    qtyElement.val(0);   // or qtyElement.val(1); if you want minimum of 1 
}
```

Comment: Both input fields have the same classes, parent classes, etc :(

Comment: I do see where you are going with this though, thank you for your input so far!

Comment: Wow, thank you this is fantastic! You are incredible, you've absolutely made my day :D

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) method to look for the enclosing parent element and then find the input field.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.qty').prop('disabled', true);
  $(document).on('click', '.plus', function (event) {
    var field = $(event.target).closest('.woocommerce').find('.qty');
    $(field).val(parseInt($('.qty').val()) + 1);
  });
  $(document).on('click', '.minus', function (event) {
    var field = $(event.target).closest('.woocommerce').find('.qty');
    $(field).val(parseInt($('.qty').val()) - 1);
    if ($('.qty').val() == 0) {
        $('.qty').val(1);
    }
  });
});
```